# How do I prevent Visual Studio from trying to step into third party dlls?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I try to step thru code using F11 in VS2012, VS throws the error below. The code its trying to find is a dll reference (Gallio.dll)

[image]

I already tried whats shown in the image below. What else can I try, so that VS doesn't try to step into a third party dll?
[image]